# how to identify the outgoing IP of a machine

Tags: c#

I have a console app in which I have to get the ip details and push it to some remote server for caching.

If my machine have multiple Ethernet interface cards, then the normal implementation will return all the ip's, both the internal ones and external one. I only need the IP from which traffic will be going out. Is there any way to identify this without making any call to any sites using c#?

Comment: Use service like `ipecho.net` or `ipchicken.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
private IPAddress GetExternalIPAddress()
{
    IPHostEntry myIPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

    foreach (IPAddress myIPAddress in myIPHostEntry.AddressList)
    {
        byte[] ipBytes = myIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();

        if( myIPAddress.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork )
        {
            if (!IsPrivateIP(myIPAddress))
            {
                return myIPAddress;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}


private bool IsPrivateIP(IPAddress myIPAddress)
{
    if (myIPAddress.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        byte[] ipBytes = myIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();

        // 10.0.0.0/24 
        if (ipBytes[0] == 10)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // 172.16.0.0/16
        else if (ipBytes[0] == 172 && ipBytes[1] == 16)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // 192.168.0.0/16
        else if (ipBytes[0] == 192 && ipBytes[1] == 168)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // 169.254.0.0/16
        else if (ipBytes[0] == 169 && ipBytes[1] == 254)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


private bool CompareIpAddress(IPAddress IPAddress1, IPAddress IPAddress2)
{
    byte[] b1 = IPAddress1.GetAddressBytes();
    byte[] b2 = IPAddress2.GetAddressBytes();

    if (b1.Length == b2.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < b1.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (b1[i] != b2[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

> This CSharp (C#) code snippet shows how to get the external IP address (IPv4) of a machine (i.e. dialup connection IP). To achieve this we get all ip addresses of the machine and compare them against the local address ranges (10.0.0.0/24, 172.16.0.0/16, 192.168.0.0/16 and 169.254.0.0/16).

[Source](https://www.stickler.de/en/information/code-snippets/get-external-ip)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one active external IP address (and possibly multiple internal addresses) you can just filter the IP address list on [reserved IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses). The remaining address is the one used for outgoing (e.g WAN/Internet) traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If specific DNS has a value, then you can understand it's the active one
[image]